# moving a git folder from local computer to an existing repo - commit history included

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to move a folder (let's call it "projectA") I've started with git version control in local computer- it has not repo connected

I would like to move "projectA" along with its history commit to a new repo called projectB.

```
projectA - this is stored in local computer and has no github repo
  app

projectB
  folder1
  folder2
  projectA - 'final destination'
```

So far I understand I have to do `git clone` for projectB, but after that I don't know to transfer projectA with its history commit under ProjectB.

Can anybody help me with this?  I only know the basics of git - add commit pull push.  Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Project A create a new branch

```
git checkout -b project_a_work
```

Add remote github repo for Project B

```
git remote add origin git@github.com/project_b.git
```

Do a git fetch and checkout project B master(any other branch you want to merge on)

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
```

Now merge the Project A work on Project B's current checkout branch

```
git merge project_a_work
```

OR

If you want all Project A history to be written after last commit on Project B, you can do git rebase

```
git rebase project_a_work
```

Comment: this works but I noticed only the contents under Project A got transferred.  The idea was to have the projectA folder along with its contents under projectB repo.

Comment: Oh, ok. If thats the case then after creating the branch 'project_a_work' you should move all your Project A content into a new sub folder and do commit. Rest of the steps remain the same. Or else you can just move the contents now by creating a new folder. History for project A is already there which was your primary concern.